# Why is my CSS padding not spacing out my unordered list?

Tags: html, css, brackets

I'm making a simple website for a class, and I can't seem to get my links to be spread out from each other. Here's the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 100px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #1e1e1e padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to get them spaced apart evenly with the `padding: 0 20px;` not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly. Sorry for noob question, thanks for any help.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in your `ul li a` block. Also, there is no need to use float: left on your `li` items.

Comment: Well I feel quite stupid lol. I looked at this code for about 30 minutes and didn't find that.

Comment: Also, it's almost always easier to use something like flex layout (demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ubhroxfj/1/), rather than `display: inline-block;` and `float`

Comment: Thank you, good to know. This is the first thing I've done with HTML/CSS and I basically know nothing about it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It´s because you have a type error in your code.
It shoud be:

```
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```